# Azure CDN (Verizon) custom rewrite rule invalid origin

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-cdn

I am trying to update 2 rules in Azure CDN Management (Verizon)
Recently they update to V4 and the prefix source is no longer coming on the field

Rule 1 -> If http redirect to https
Rule 2 -> If url is empty (only root) serve default document index.html

The new rules engine is unable to identify the Source
I already try

1. Leaving it blank
2. www.[mydomain].com
3. [mydomain].com
4. /

The old version had the CDN Verizon id hardcoded on the field, maybe this what is missing? how can I find this?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm having similar issue but prepending my regex with the value you've identified still gives the `Source must contain a valid Origin` error.  I've read through the documentation on Verizon that agrees with your format (see https://docs.vdms.com/cdn/Content/HRE/F/URL-Rewrite.htm) but I can't get it to work.  I've posted here, and wonder if you have thoughts (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62093666/what-is-the-correct-azure-cli-command-for-creating-http-rules-on-cdn-endpoints)   Thanks

Answer (score 33):

Managed to get the correct values by playing around with other options

To get your customer ORIGIN 
-> Create new rule

-> Origin -> Customer Origin

-> Copy entire line /80*****/***

-> Use this line to populate your origin on the redirect rule

Comment: This definitely works - although it feels ridiculous that this is the path to finding a value for a required field.

Comment: It was selectable from dropdown in previous version of Rules Engine

Comment: Just to add, this approach only works with the `HTTP Large` platform, not the `ADN` platform.

Comment: you saved me a ton of time boss!

Comment: @AdiUnnithan comment about using HTTP Large is one of the keys here.