# What is the correct Azure CLI command for creating HTTP Rules on CDN Endpoints (Verizon Premium edition)?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, cdn, verizon

Or reworded another way, can someone provide explanations for the different parameters for the `az cdn endpoint rule add` command?

The Verizon [documentation](https://docs.vdms.com/cdn/index.html#Quick_References/HRE_QR.htm#Conditio) doesn't match up very well with the Azure CLI.

Verizon have moved from their v3 Rule Engine to v4, and while it is a massive improvement for layout and usability, it still doesn't provide information on what the specific fields are, or how they would map to the Azure CLI `az cdn endpoint rule add` command.

One problem is that the new v4 interface has lost the "source" drop list with the internally created Verizon Id.

@Christopher Cabezudo Rodriguez has [bruteforced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697519/azure-cdn-verizon-custom-rewrite-rule-invalid-origin)  how to get this value, but it doesn't help when trying to set this up using the CLI.

I have 3 HTTP Rules I want to create.

1. The first HTTP rule allows our Angular Single Page Application “SPA” to work where navigation clicks that change the URL Address don’t reload or navigate away from the page.
2. The second HTTP rule restricts HTTP traffic to route to HTTPS.
3. The third HTTP rule tells the browser to always check to see if anything has changed between the CDN and the Cache.  This will ensure that the user always downloads the latest version of the client application.

To Start with, I create the CDN and Endpoint like this:

```
az cdn profile create --name $AZ_APP_CDN --resource-group $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_APP --location $AZ_LOCATION --sku Premium_Verizon

az cdn endpoint create --name $AZ_APP_CDN_ENDPOINT --resource-group $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_APP --profile-name $AZ_APP_CDN --origin $ST_BLOB_ORIGIN_DOMAIN --no-http true
```

In the V4 Rules Engine they would look like this:

[image]

I've half-arsed together my best guess of what I might need as CLI commands to this:

```
az cdn endpoint rule add -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_APP -n $AZ_APP_CDN_ENDPOINT --profile-name $AZ_APP_CDN --order 0 --rule-name "Redirect" --match-variable RequestHeaderWildcard --match-variable "User-Agent" --operator Equal --match-values "ECPurge/*"--negate-condition true  --action-name "UrlRewrite" --source-pattern "[^?.]*(\?.*)?$" --custom-fragment "client/index.html"

az cdn endpoint rule add -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_APP -n $AZ_APP_CDN_ENDPOINT --profile-name $AZ_APP_CDN --order 1 --rule-name "Http to Https" --match-variable RequestScheme --operator Equal --match-values HTTPS --action-name "UrlRedirect" --redirect-protocol Https --redirect-type Moved

az cdn endpoint rule add -g $AZ_RESOURCE_GROUP_APP -n $AZ_APP_CDN_ENDPOINT --profile-name $AZ_APP_CDN --order 2 --rule-name "Overwrite cache-control header" --match-variable Always --operator Equal --match-values HTTPS --action-name "ModifyClientResponseHeader" --header-action "Overwrite" --header-name "CacheControl" --header-value "max-age=0, must-revalidate, public"
```

Special mention that the second rule is actually given by the CLI help as an example, but it doesn't work.  See:

`az cdn endpoint rule add -h`

For each of the above commands, I get the following 3 errors (numbered according to the rule):

1. BadRequest - Name must be left blank for delivery rules in Verizon profiles
2. validation error: Parameter 'DeliveryRuleAction.name' can not be None.
3. az cdn endpoint rule add: error: the following arguments are required: --order, --rule-name, --action-name

Any help greatly appreciated ... I'll still keep banging my head against this wall and post if I work it out.

UPDATE: For not wanting to state the obvious, with Error #1 above, if I remove the `--name` parameter (as the error suggests), I get the following error instead:

`(--name | --ids) are required`

UPDATE 2: The following Azure [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cdn/endpoint/rule/action?view=azure-cli-latest) suggests `az cdn endpoint rule action add` is correct, but it still doesn't work (provides cryptic error as per below).

The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rules'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\knack\knack\cli.py", line 215, in invoke
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 631, in execute
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 695, in _run_jobs_serially
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 688, in _run_job
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\six\six.py", line 703, in reraise
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 665, in _run_job
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\commands\__init__.py", line 324, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\azure-cli-core\azure\cli\core\__init__.py", line 574, in default_command_handler
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7cl6xofh\azure-cli\azure\cli\command_modules\cdn\custom.py", line 396, in add_action
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rules'
```

Comment: Can we automate Verizon premium rule with Az powershell or Az CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation isn't great on this - I've found it helpful to run `debug` since ultimately new CDN rules require a POST request of all your existing CDN rules plus the one you have.

Also, you have to get certain strings like `--operator`, `--match-variable`, and `--selector` exactly as your debug output has it, otherwise you got a non-helpful error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it's a shame really.  Verizon lost a customer and we drop one Azure asset.  Instead of serving our Angular web pack from an Azure Blob storage account, we added a new node.js endpoint with the rules there to serve the files.  We can then also add the refresh rule, and restrict to only accept https from the Docker file we use to build the Azure AKS kubernetes service.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the first error. Error 2 and 3 can quite easily be solved with for example:
--action-name CacheExpiration 
--order 0 
--rule-name global \

My problem is still the --name parameter which Azure Cli doesn't accept for Verizon Sku. This is strange since an endpoint name is needed to set a cache rule on an endpoint.