# Azure CDN Premium Verizon Rules Engine V4 URL Rewrite for Storage Static Website sub directories

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn, verizon

I'm trying to host an `Angular` project with `Azure Storage Static Website` through  `Azure CDN Verizon Premium`

Let's say i have containers for each `Angular` builds named like `v0.3.13.3` and in that container there are also multi language builds of angular project.

What i'm trying to achieve is to serve the right `index.html` with correct routing for each version and language.

You may find example routes below:

`my.domain.com/v0.3.13.3` should serve `/v0.3.13.3/index.html`
`my.domain.com/v0.3.13.3/dashboard` should serve `/v0.3.13.3/index.html` 
`my.domain.com/v0.3.13.3/fr` should serve `/v0.3.13.3/fr/index.html` 
`my.domain.com/v0.3.13.3/fr/dashboard` should serve `/v0.3.13.3/fr/index.html`

I've managed to do it with `Azure Standard Rules Engine`  like the screen shot below.

[image]

But as far as i've seen from the docs, in standard rules engine `Contains` field can't be filled with regex. I've digged all over google but can't seem to find any solution that suits me.

So i've switched my CDN service to Verizon Premium and tried to apply `(v(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.\d+))` to path regex.

The main issue i'm having with Verizon Premium is that i can only apply `URL Rewrite` feature if i state my IF field to `Always`

[image]

As you can see `URL Rewrite` is not listed.

Also i've made couple of deployments using `Always`  statement but they did not any good.

The single example that everyone shares in their blogs

[image]

So above example does not cover File Extensions and sub routes.

Are there any ways to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I would share my current config that I using in Verizon Premium in Rule V4:
The steps are:

1. New rule: General Always
2. Feature: URL -> URL Rewrite
3. Source: `/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/((?:[^\?]*/)?)($|\?.*)`
4. Destination: `/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/index.html$2`
5. And add a second rule. Source: `/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/((?:[^\?]*\/)?[^\?\/.]+)($|\?.*)`
6. Destination: `/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/index.html$2`

Also you can obtainer the origin as described in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58700538/3591687

This is the XML Rule was generated

```
<policy>    
  <rules>   
    <rule>
        <match.always>
            <feature.url.url-rewrite source="/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/((?:[^\?]*/)?)($|\?.*)" destination="/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/index.html$2"/>
            <feature.url.url-rewrite source="/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/((?:[^\?]*\/)?[^\?\/.]+)($|\?.*)" destination="/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/index.html$2"/>
        </match.always>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</policy>
```

I hope that helps to somebody

Comment: This has helped me a lot, thank you.
I understand the second rule (match everything that has no "file extension"), but what do you need the first rule for? As I understand it, it would need something like `/80XXXXXX/XXXXXX/?variable` to match

Answer (score 0):

Please see below in Rules Engine 4.0 as to how you select the URL Rewrite in Azure CDN - the documentation is currently lacking and still attempting to get this to work. I will update this post once it is set up correctly
[image: Azure CDN Rule Engine 4.0]

Answer (score 0):

I had a bear of a time on this issue in March 2022 using V4 of the rules engine. I finally got the redirect to work by **duplicating the redirects** to account for both hashes for the origin server, starting with 00 and 08 in my case. It feels like the CDN is using a blue/green deployment methodology, and each time you deploy, it switches to the other server.

So if you deploy using the hash starting with 00, it will move your deployment to the 08 server.

Then you attempt to deploy using the 08 hash, and the system complains you haven't changed anything.  :)

So I just duplicated code and cried into my pillow at night.

For the record, if you attempt to deploy in the "feature.url.url-redirect source" section using a regex containing something like /[0-9]+ when you change the **draft** into a **policy**, the system will complain that the source does not match any known origin.

This is what worked for me. If someone has a more elegant solution, I welcome it!

```
<policy>
<rules>
    <rule>
        <description>Redirect HTTP to HTTPS 00 Version</description>
        <match.request.request-scheme.literal value="http">
            <feature.url.url-redirect source="/00XXXXXX/www-example-com/(.*)" destination="https://%{host}/$1" code="302"/>
        </match.request.request-scheme.literal>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <description>Redirect HTTP to HTTPS 80 Version</description>
        <match.request.request-scheme.literal value="http">
            <feature.url.url-redirect source="/80XXXXXX/www-example-com/(.*)" destination="https://%{host}/$1" code="302"/>
        </match.request.request-scheme.literal>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <description>Site redirects to 00 Version</description>
        <match.request.request-scheme.literal value="https">
            <select.first-match>
                <match.url.url-path.regex result="match" value="[\/#]*\/dir1\/subdir1.*" ignore-case="true" encoded="false">
                    <feature.url.url-redirect source="/00XXXXXX/www-example-com/.*" destination="https://www.example.com/#/dir1/subdir1" code="302"/>
                </match.url.url-path.regex>
                <match.url.url-path.regex result="match" value="[\/#]*\/folder2\/subfolder2.*" ignore-case="true" encoded="false">
                    <feature.url.url-redirect source="/00XXXXXX/www-example-com/.*" destination="https://www.example.com/#/folder2/subfolder2" code="302"/>
                </match.url.url-path.regex>
                <match.url.url-path.regex result="match" value=".*" ignore-case="true" encoded="false">
                    <feature.url.url-redirect source="/00XXXXXX/www-example-com/.*" destination="https://www.example.com/" code="302"/>
                </match.url.url-path.regex>
            </select.first-match>
        </match.request.request-scheme.literal>
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <description>Site redirects to 80 Version</description>
        <match.request.request-scheme.literal value="https">
            <select.first-match>
                <match.url.url-path.regex result="match" value="[\/#]*\/dir1\/subdir1.*" ignore-case="true" encoded="false">
                    <feature.url.url-redirect source="/80XXXXXX/www-example-com/.*" destination="https://www.example.com/#/dir1/subdir1" code="302"/>
                </match.url.url-path.regex>
                <match.url.url-path.regex result="match" value="[\/#]*\/folder2\/subfolder2.*" ignore-case="true" encoded="false">
                    <feature.url.url-redirect source="/80XXXXXX/www-example-com/.*" destination="https://www.example.com/#/folder2/subfolder2" code="302"/>
                </match.url.url-path.regex>
                <match.url.url-path.regex result="match" value=".*" ignore-case="true" encoded="false">
                    <feature.url.url-redirect source="/80XXXXXX/www-example-com/.*" destination="https://www.example.com/" code="302"/>
                </match.url.url-path.regex>
            </select.first-match>
        </match.request.request-scheme.literal>
    </rule>
</rules>
```