# Azure CDN url rewrite for react app not working

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

I'm trying to host a React app in Azure blob storage. To do this I need to rewrite all requests to /index.html, while preserving the url in the browser. Various articles describe using Azure CDN to perform the URL Rewrite to direct all requests through index.html. I haven't been able to get this working, here's what I have tried:

[image: Less than]

[image: regex]

This is what i'm trying to achieve:
[image: example]

Comment: After reading your description, you can carefully describe the effect you want, such as what is the access URL and what is the rewritten URL?

Comment: I think what you need is url redirect, not url rewrite.

Comment: question updated, thanks. It does need to be a rewrite and not a redirect as the url needs to be preserved

Comment: You should create CDN resource in the portal with `Premium Verizon`  pricing tier.

Comment: [Blogs 1](https://medium.com/@antbutcher89/hosting-a-react-js-app-on-azure-blob-storage-azure-cdn-for-ssl-and-routing-8fdf4a48feeb)  clearly tells us how to use it, but currently there seems to be a problem with rule engine 4.0. It is recommended to use web.config for rewrite.

Comment: If you still want to use cdn for rewrite, you can refer to the document for operation. These two posts should also be helpful to you. [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58697519/azure-cdn-verizon-custom-rewrite-rule-invalid-origin) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62647432/azure-cdn-premium-verizon-rules-engine-v4-url-rewrite-for-storage-static-website).

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jason, I'm currently waiting for Microsoft support to get back to me as they think it should be possible in the standard rules engine (cheaper than verizon premium). Will update here when I hear from them.

Comment: If you solved the issue, you can post your answer here can help more forum user.

Comment: hasn't been resolved yet, I will post answer if it ever comes

Comment: If possible, you can add `web.config` file to use rewrite.

Comment: it's hosted in azure storage - web.config will only work if i host in a web app right?

Comment: I'm not sure, you can try it. If failed, you need to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve this using this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63197547/983599

I had basically picked the wrong condition type, instead of "Request URL" less than 1, it should have been "URL file extension":

[image]

Comment: I tried to achieve same kind of thing but there is no more URL file extension into the Rule Engine V4. Could you add the Raw XML rule that is generated please ?